# MassTransit + Azure Service Bus - 2 duplicated receivers and queues created on attempt to configure auto-forwarding from topic to queue

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, masstransit

I try to configure azure service bus auto-forwarding from topic to queue (since topic does not support ScheduledRedelivery)

**Actual result** - it works - but creates 2 subscriptions instead of one - update-auction-on-auction-updated2, UpdateAuctionOnAuctionUpdatedReceiver2 (and two destination queues for each one - update-auction-on-auction-updated2, UpdateAuctionOnAuctionUpdatedReceiver2).
As a result - receiver called twice for every message produced to AuctionApproved topic.

**Expected result** - receiver calls once, only one receiver and queue created on auto-forwarding

**MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core - 8.1.2 version**
Here is code:

```
// receiver - AuctionApproved is message type in topic
public class UpdateAuctionOnAuctionApprovedReceiver : UpdateAuctionReceiverBase<AuctionApproved>
{
    ...
}
// here I try to configure azure service bus auto-forwarding from topic to queue (since topic does not support ScheduledRedelivery)
 configurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((rc, cfg) =>
            {
   cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(
                    "update-auction-on-auction-approved",
                    e =>
                    {
                        e.UseScheduledRedelivery(RedeliveryConfig);
                        e.Consumer<UpdateAuctionOnAuctionApprovedReceiver>(rc);
                    });
}
```